# Problem while trying to scroll window to an element position using intersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, intersection-observer

I'm trying to make slide-show website using intersectionObserver. Basically, i grep elements and listen for intersection event, then i want to set window.srollTo to element's offsetTop. I have tried window.scrollTo(0, 10), elem.scrollIntoView(), window.scrollBy(), but nothing is working at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body,
      html {
        position: ablolute;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        display: block;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
      }
      body::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0 !important;
      }

      .page {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">one</div>
    <div class="page">two</div>
    <div class="page">three</div>
    <div class="page">four</div>
    <script>

      const pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        entries => {
          entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting == true) {

              console.log(entry.target.offsetTop);
              entry.target.scrollIntoView(top);
            }
          });
        },
        {threshold: 0.01},
      );
      pages.forEach(page => {
        observer.observe(page);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `entry.target.scrollIntoView(top);` Where did `top` come from?

Comment: Hi Maksym, please can you edit the title of your post. It is not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `scrollIntoView` takes a `Boolean` or an options `Object`. I don't know what `top` is supposed to be since it's not in your code, but it's not correct.

Your scroll event is firing constantly and overriding your `scrollIntoView`. In order to stop this you can set the container's `overflow` property so that it no longer allows scrolling, disabling the event, and then re-enable it with a timer just before calling `scrollIntoView`.

```
          entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting == true) {

          console.log(entry.target.offsetTop);
          document.body.setAttribute('style','overflow:hidden;');

          setTimeout(function(){
           document.body.setAttribute('style','overflow:visible;');       
           entry.target.scrollIntoView(true);
           }, 250);

        }
```

---

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body,
      html {
        position: absolute;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        display: block;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
      }
      body::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0 !important;
      }

      .page {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">one</div>
    <div class="page">two</div>
    <div class="page">three</div>
    <div class="page">four</div>
    <script>
      const pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        entries => {
          entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting == true) {

              console.log(entry.target.offsetTop);
              document.body.setAttribute('style','overflow:hidden;');

              setTimeout(function(){
               document.body.setAttribute('style','overflow:visible;');       
               entry.target.scrollIntoView(true);
               }, 250);
        
            }
          });
        },
        {threshold: 0.10},
      );
      pages.forEach(page => {
        observer.observe(page);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note** There are likely better ways to do this without a timer - for instance a flag within a closure, etc, but this should give you an idea of what's causing the issue and how to get around it.